# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report! - Sept 2017

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, monthly

## Welcome Our SharePoint Stack Exchange Valued Contributors.

We would like to share with you the **Most Active Contributors Report** over the last month!

[image]

**This report includes the following awards:**

1. Monthly Leader Board.
2. Most Active Contributors Award.
3. Most Active Editors Award.
4. Most Active Voters Award.
5. Most Close Votes Review Award.
6. Most First Post Review Award.
7. Most Late Answer Review Award.
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.
9. Most Reopen Review Award.
10. Most Suggested Edit Review Award.
11. Highest Votes Questions Award.
12. Highest Votes Answers Award.
13. Most Viewed Questions Award.
14. 1st Top Contributors summary list.

---

[image]

[image]

You can find the full list at [Stack Exchange Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/105/month/sharepoint/2017-09-02)

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                   REPUTATION
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                   1,665
2   Gautam Sheth               875
3   Waqas Sarwar MVP           555
4   Ahmad Zia                  500
5   Youssef Moumen El idrissi  480
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                    EDITS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                   125
2   Robert Lindgren            21
3   Youssef Moumen El idrissi  17
4   Waqas Sarwar MVP           17
5   Arsalan Adam Khatri        12
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     VOTES
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Zsmaster                   440
2   Well                       347
3   Adam                       159
4   Aashirya                   128
5   Michelle                   119
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                     29
2   Gautam Sheth                 13
3   Aakash Morya                 11
4   Asad Refai                   11
5   P S                          7
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   hoffie4                      94
2   M.Qassas                     62
3   Aakash Morya                 32
4   P S                          27
5   Gautam Sheth                 19
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                     42
2   hoffie4                      27
3   P S                          10
4   Robert Lindgren              9
5   Gaurravs                     9
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                     57
2   Gautam Sheth                 31
3   P S                          30
4   Aakash Morya                 29
5   Robert Lindgren              17
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   P S                          5
2   M.Qassas                     5
3   moe                          4
4   Asad Refai                   4
5   Gautam Sheth                 3
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                     38
2   Trevor Seward                23
3   Aakash Morya                 17
4   P S                          14
5   Robert Lindgren              12
```

---

[image]

1. [Why is it not working properly when I add JavaScript, HTML, and CSS code?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226128/why-is-it-not-working-properly-when-i-add-javascript-html-and-css-code)

   - **Quest Owner:** f_gulay.
   - **Votes:** 7.
2. [Difference between list workflow and site workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226098/difference-between-list-workflow-and-site-workflow)

   - **Quest Owner:** Curious.
   - **Votes:** 6.
3. [Unable to call graph API from SharePoint page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225389/unable-to-call-graph-api-from-sharepoint-page)

   - **Quest Owner:** Ashish.
   - **Votes:** 6.

---

[image]

1. [SharePoint Framework: How to detect if running on modern or classic page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225050/sharepoint-framework-how-to-detect-if-running-on-modern-or-classic-page/225058#225058)

   - **Answer Owner:** Gautam Sheth.
   - **Votes:** 7.
2. [How do I hide edit this list?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226291/how-do-i-hide-edit-this-list/226293#226293)

   - **Answer Owner:** Dikesh Gandhi.
   - **Votes:** 6.
3. [What is the permission level for giving permission for other users?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226803/what-is-the-permission-level-for-give-permission-for-other-user/226805#226805)

   - **Answer Owner:** M.Qassas.
   - **Votes:** 6.

---

[image]

1. [Why is it not working properly when I add JavaScript, HTML, and CSS code?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226128/why-is-it-not-working-properly-when-i-add-javascript-html-and-css-code)

   - **Views:** 789.
2. [How do I hide edit this list?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226291/how-do-i-hide-edit-this-list/226293#226293)

   - **Views:** 350.
3. [What is the permission level for giving permission for other users?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226803/what-is-the-permission-level-for-give-permission-for-other-user/226805#226805)

   - **Views:** 309.

---

[image]

1. **Most Active Contributors Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
2. **Most Active Editors Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas)  Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
3. **Most Active Voters Award.**

   - [Zsmaster](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/69884/zsmaster) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
4. **Most Close Votes Review Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
5. **Most First Post Review Award.**

   - [hoffie4](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/52982/hoffie4) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
6. **Most Late Answer Review Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
7. **Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas)  Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
8. **Most Reopen Review Award.**

   - [P S](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/41198/p-s) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
9. **Most Suggested Edit Review Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
10. **Highest Votes Questions Award.**

    - [f_gulay](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/69910/f-gulay) Great Question, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
11. **Highest Votes Answers Award.**

    - [Gautam Sheth](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/8068/gautam-sheth) Great Answer, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
12. **Most Viewed Questions Award.**

    - [Why is it not working properly when I add JavaScript, HTML, and CSS code?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226128/why-is-it-not-working-properly-when-i-add-javascript-html-and-css-code)

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering, We fully appreciate all the great contributions of SE members. Please keep your valuable contributing!

> **P.S.:** This report will be published Monthly / Quarterly / Yearly. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback & precious suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations to each of you. Your valuable contributions will always helpful. Keep it up.